# Interaction (in linear regression) ignores one of the discrete variable's levels

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I am fitting a **dataframe** with the linear regression model that includes interaction:

```
lm0 <- lm(Mean_RT ~ POS*Length, data = df)
```

The output of `summary()` function is:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   582.040     16.701  34.851   <2e-16 ***
POSVB         -55.523     33.810  -1.642    0.101    
Length         25.064      1.958  12.803   <2e-16 ***
POSVB:Length    4.147      4.131   1.004    0.316
```

I don't understand why it just uses POSVB and not POSNN (and POSNN:Length) in the coefficients?

The **dataframe**:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is accounting for POSNN. Consider the equation that you (i.e. R) constructed:

$y_i = \beta_0 + \text{POS}_i\times \beta_1 + \text{Length}_i\times \beta_2 + \text{POS}_i\times \text{Length}_i\times \beta_3$

Where $\text{POS}_i$ may take values 0 (NN) and 1 (VB) by the way R converts factors into dummy-coded binary predictors. Length, presumably, can take some positive real-valued number.

Should you have a NN item, then the equation simplifies to $y_i = \beta_0 + \text{Length}\times \beta_2$. Therefore, we have the effect of NN (just the intercept) in interaction with $\text{Length}$. You need estimated coefficients $\beta_0$ and $\beta_2$. There's no $\text{POS}_i\times \text{Length}_i$ for $\text{POS}_i=0$ because this would just be 0.

Should you have an VB item, then you need estimated coefficients $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, and $\beta_3$ (since $\text{POS}_i$ will be 1).

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense.

Comment: Great! I'm pretty sure there are many similar questions on dummy-coded variables in regressions on this SE, consider searching if you'd like other answers.

Comment: what would happen if the factor could take three values? I assume it is no longer binary coded? Basically imagine $POS_i$ could take another value like DD. What would be the corresponding $y_i$ for DD? Assuming NN is still 0, and VB is 1.

Comment: @user3639557 good question, simple answer. There are a lot of resources on regression, and almost any stats textbook will answer your questions. Here's [one arbitrary (but seemingly decent) resource](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05728.pdf) I found.